Do We Still Need to Learn About Boltzmann Machines?
When looking at the deep learning courses offered by top universities in the United States that are available online (not MOOCs, but actual classes), a few schools still cover (Restricted) Boltzmann Machines, although they are not many. However, I noticed that these techniques are not frequently applied nowadays. It could serve as a basic introduction to generative models, but I think it would be fine to go straight to VAEs and GANs.
In this context, is there an educational, academic, or practical reason to teach concepts related to (Restricted) Boltzmann Machines?
